is it okay to download files using post routes?
i am sending csv buffer as stream from backend
and in frontend i am using post route
but for post route i need to download blob in fronend code
if i make it as get route in backend it downloads
although i am keeping headers in post route as attatchent
still i need to handle blob in frontend
any suggestions?
is there any way such that
in backend i have post route
and in fronend i just hit the route and it automatically downloads withput blob stuff
and is there any way such that my data in response is hidden
i dont want to show response in network tab.
